# AWS Elastic Load balancer not working for rails devise gem. Getting invalid Authenticity Token error

Tags: devise, amazon-elb

AWS Elastic Load balancer not working for rails devise gem. Getting invalid Authenticity Token error.
Need to use AWS load balancer without sticky sessions for ruby on rails devise gem. But it gives invalid authenticity token error. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, and did not found a solution yet :(